# Switchable Gain Op Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

From this [App Note](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-2566-Single-Phase-Power-Energy-Meter-with-Tamper-Detection_Ap-Notes_AVR465.pdf):

> Gain adjustment resistors are dimensioned such that each range has an
>   amplification of about eight times the previous. The number of
>   switches may well be increased and the gain difference decreased,
>   however, it is not recommended to have a larger gain difference than
>   eight between two subsequent ranges. This because gain differences of
>   around ten, and higher, cause the signal to degrade below 1% accuracy
>   before it can be further amplified.

[image]

I'm planing to have two gains: 1 and 33. However, the difference is larger than the recommended. Is this actually a problem? It says it may cause the signal to degrade. Do you agree?

Comment: Without knowing what ADC you plan to use this can't be answered. Also what accuracy is required?

Comment: I'm using a 12-bit ADC. I can accept up to 2% accuracy

Answer (score 1):

write an error budget.

This requires

1) understanding the detailed behavior of the entire circuit,

2) determining the partial_derivatives at the operating point(s) so dVout/dR2 is
a known number.

3) algebraically summing the various partials, and see if the result (including ADC DNL & INL & quantization noise) is less than your 2% goal, at least 90% of the time.

4) or you can run a myriad Monte Carlo simulations, and pretend to be understanding your system